# Criar banco de dados através do PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com um projeto em mente, no qual eu gostaria de criar banco de dados com o nome de variáveis, e no caso seria feito um check para saber se o BD já foi criado, ficaria algo nesse estilo:

```
    if ($pdo=new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$var","root",""))=sucess 
    {
       "não cria BD"
    }else{
       CREATE DATABASE $var
    }
```

Isso é possível?

**OBS**: não preciso realmente fazer isso mas ficaria muito mais organizado caso seja possível.

Comment: Toda vez que faz algo que não precisa fica menos organizado.

Comment: No caso do código sim, mas o BD ficaria ainda mais caso isso não seja possível.

Comment: Não vejo como isto faça sentido, mas você pode tentar mostrar como.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```